# How to perform UTF-8 encoding using xmlstarlet fo --encode option?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, xmlstarlet

The synopsis for xmlstarlet fo says

```
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Format XML document
Usage: xmlstarlet fo [<options>] <xml-file>
where <options> are
  -n or --noindent            - do not indent
  -t or --indent-tab          - indent output with tabulation
  -s or --indent-spaces <num> - indent output with <num> spaces
  -o or --omit-decl           - omit xml declaration <?xml version="1.0"?>
  --net                       - allow network access
  -R or --recover             - try to recover what is parsable
  -D or --dropdtd             - remove the DOCTYPE of the input docs
  -C or --nocdata             - replace cdata section with text nodes
  -N or --nsclean             - remove redundant namespace declarations
  -e or --encode <encoding>   - output in the given encoding (utf-8, unicode...)
  -H or --html                - input is HTML
  -h or --help                - print help
```

When I run

`cat unformatted.html | xmlstarlet fo -H -R --encode utf-8`

I am returned the error message

`failed to load external entity "utf-8"`

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience, xmlstarlet `fo` especially, needs the `stdin` dash to work (better).

In your example, the 'unformatted.html' contents are piped to xmlstarlet.
But xmlstarlet `fo` doesn't *'see'* the piped input, if you don't use a `-` (dash).

It assumes that the last argument (`utf-8`) is the filename ("external entity") whose contents you're trying to format. Obviously, there's no such file. Just to be on the safe side, I'd also enclose the encoding argument with double quotes, like so: `"utf-8"`.

Altering your statement to

```bash
xmlstarlet fo -H -R --encode "utf-8" unformatted.html
```

should do the trick.

The `cat` is [unnecessary](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award), I'd think.